# Smart home device integration with Google home and Alexa

Tags: mqtt, alexa-skills-kit, google-smart-home, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am trying to integrate smart home devices with Google home and Alexa but I am facing following issue.

1. Communication between Google Home/Alexa and our device cloud server is HTTP.
2. Communication between smart home device and our device cloud server is MQTT.

How do I keep track of synchronous request-response? Is there a better way to implement this system?

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly possibly to do with HTTP to MQTT and back again.

I've done it for both Alexa & Google Home for my Node-RED nodes.

You just need to keep track of on going requests and include a unique id in the request/response MQTT messages while also running a timer to handle no response from the device.

Comment: Okay. Can you point me to some link where I can refer the code ?

Comment: Is this technique reliable for production environment?

Comment: It gets a bit more complex when you have to horizontally scale, but it can be made to work

Answer (score 0):

The project gBridge (https://github.com/kservices/gBridge; https://about.gbridge.io) basically implements plain Google Assistant/ Alexa to MQTT bridging.

Regarding your questions, there are two points that help to implement these solutions:

1. Think in terms of devices or endpoints, rather than requests. When you just want to "translate" HTTP to MQTT, you are inducing a lot of issues like you've figured out. You probably want to implement a logic that allows MQTT topics to control/ query your actual deviecs - not ones that respond to HTTP requests. This makes thing a whole lot simpler.
2. Caching is essential. Allow your bridge to have a local copy of your device's states. When having the properly implemented cache, you won't need for any response. Just use the cached data.